# Custom Comparator is not doing enough Comparison

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, compare, comparison

I want to sort values based on following criteria:
If sum of values at i & j is odd then only values should be swapped. Output string should be lexicographically smallest possible.

Input: 1 2 5 3 8 10 32 51 5 8
Output: 1 2 5 3 8 10 32 51 5 8
Desired Output: 1 2 5 3 5 10 32 8 8 51

I'm using this piece of code. but it is not giving desired result.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Integer>()
        {
            public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
                if ((a + b) % 2 != 0)
                    return a - b;
                else
               return 0;
            }
        });
```

Comment: can u explain what do u mean by i & j ?

Comment: Lexigraphically, isn't `"1 10 2 3 32 5 5"` smaller than  `"1 2 5 3 5 10 32"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) for `Comparator.compare` says

> Finally, the implementor must ensure that compare(x, y) == 0 implies that sgn(compare(x, z)) == sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z.

But your `Comparator` does not meet this condition when `x = 0`, `y = 2`, `z = 1`.

```
0 == 2
0 < 1
2 > 1
```

This is not a problem of your implementation, but of what you are trying to do.